# How to take screencast for android app for read_insights permission?

Tags: android, facebook, admob, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

I submitted an [android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tofabd.batteryanalyzer) to facebook for read_insights permission to show ads on my app. Facebook authority didn't approve it. I'm using Google's admob mediation to show ads on my app.
They said, "Your screencast doesn't show how the use of this permission directly improves the user experience in your app."

My screencast show facebook test ads. How can I show the use of this (read_insights) permission? Google's admob mediation fetches ads from facebook using read_insights permission. And admob provides ads to my app.
Screencast link which I submitted:
https://youtu.be/Jp7u1rwubKY

[image]

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am going through the same situation I need to get permission.